# Call to undefined Function and array keys in PHP even though it has been clearly been defined?

Tags: php, html, sql

Hey guys so currently I am teaching myself PHP but have come across a very confusing issue. I am getting the following errors when running another file that includes this code in a separate file.

> Warning: Undefined array key "first_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\classes\signup.php on line 26
> Warning: Undefined array key "last_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\classes\signup.php on line 27
> Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\classes\signup.php on line 28
> Warning: Undefined array key "password" in C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\classes\signup.php on line 29
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_userid() in C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\classes\signup.php:32 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\classes\signup.php(17): Signup->create_user(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\signup.php(7): Signup->evaluate(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MirrorTrade\classes\signup.php on line 32

And here is my code that is having issues

```
<?php

class Signup
{
private $error = "";
public function evaluate($data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
            {
            if(empty($value))
            {
                $this->error = $this->error . $key . " is empty!<br>";
            }
        }
        if($this->error == "")
        {
            $this->create_user($data);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->error;
        }
    }
public function create_user($data)
    {
        $firstname = $data['first_name'];
        $lastname = $data['last_name'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        $url_address = strtolower($firstname) . "." . strtolower($lastname);
        $userid = create_userid();

        $query = "insert into 
        users
        (userid,first_name,last_name,email,password,url_address)
        values
        ('$userid','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password','$url_address')";
        return $query;
    }
    
private function create_userid()
    {
        $length = rand(4,19);
        $number = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) 
        { 
            $new_rand = rand(0,9);
            $number = $number . $new_rand;
        }
        return $number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer to another method inside the same class, you need to prefix it with `$this`. So this code:

```
$userid = create_userid();
```

Should be:

```
$userid = $this->create_userid();
```

Also note, your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

And **never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I understand my code is not completely safe and is vulnerable but this is covered later in the videos I am following :) Thank you!